# Team Foundation 2010 - Excel server workbook security prompts

Tags: excel

When trying to open excel TFS reports from within Visual Studio we keep getting prompted by excel for security credentials. It says it is trying to connect to

```
'http://myserver.mydomain.com'.
```

When I open the project portal using the above domain name in a browser and then try to open the report I get the prompt.

When I use just the server name, in other words,

```
'http://myserver'
```

to access the report, the security prompt goes away.

How do I configure TFS (or Visual Studio or whatever) so that when opening excel TFS reports it uses just the server name?

Comment: Try adding the myserver.mydomain.com to your trusted servers in the Internet Explorer settings. This has to do with Domain trust and you'll probably get a better answer on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried that before posting here. No go.

Answer (score 2):

I have definitely run into this one before.  It's a safety feature for Excel paired with SharePoint Document Libraries.

Essentially, here are the steps to "trust" the site:

1. Open Excel
2. Open Excel Options from the Backstage View
3. Head to Trust Center on right side at the very bottom.
4. Click "Trust Center Settings"
   [image: Excel Trust Center]
5. Click Trusted Locations
6. There are several things you want to do here next.  If you want to trust network locations then click that option to enable it.
7. If you want to add a new trusted location then click "Add new location..."
8. Type in the full URL for the new location and then choose the box for "Subfolders of this location are also trusted."
   [image: Adding a Trusted Location in Excel Trust Center]

That should do it!

BTW - from my un, you can have your IT department send these settings to all computers on your Active Directory domain through global policies so others don't have to go through these steps.  They can also add this site to the Intranet Sites group in Internet Explorer for everyone internally which should help out in other similar scenarios.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I am still being prompted. 2 things to note: 1) is that the excel work book still loads the tfs data despite the prompts and 2) after following your instructions I am only prompted once now (I was prompted twice previously). Any more ideas?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what else it is.  Can you update with screenshots of the prompt you are now seeing?

Comment: Ed, thanks for your time on this. I am starting to think this is a dns issue on my network or something. I am going to verify with my network admin before continuing.